# how do i make browser display my code changes right away

Tags: css, web, browser, frontend

I am working on a web app and displaying my interfaces using wampserver localhost on chrome browser.
When I change the styling of the web pages they don't display on my browser right away, however if I try the same code next day, it works.
sometimes I have to use inline css to force styles to appear.
and if I try the same codes on JSFiddle the styles show normally.
is there a way to make my browser digest code changes faster?

Comment: it's probably caching... Browsers try to be smart by not requesting the same files from the same source in a short period of time (they keep a copy of it - in a local cache - and try to re-use it as much as possible) you can try forcing the browser to request all the files each time when you refresh your page by pressing `CTRL + F5` or `CTRL + Shift + R` (R for refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try refreshing your browser by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, this will invalidate the cache and force the browser to reload the latest changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just try hard refresh By Ctrl +Shift+ R  it will solve your cache problem.Second is
open the same page in incognito tab if it is working there then it surely the cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could always give your style sheet a unique parameter after the name specifying a version e.g. "mystylesheets.css?ver-2022-07-12.1"  The browser will read this as a new style sheet.  Works for scripts too. :)